# Can I exclude certain settings with VS Code built-in settings sync feature?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the built-in Settings Sync feature (comes with VS Code 1.46 or somewhere later), logged in with my GitHub account. I would like to exclude some settings from syncing, keeping them separate per installation. For example, "font size" is among those that I don't want to sync.

I'm currently running Code 1.50.1. Is it possible to keep *a selected set* of settings from syncing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to the settings file. This should work:

```json
{
    "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [
    "editor.fontSize"
    ]
}
```

For keyboard shortcuts:

```json
{
   "settingsSync.keybindingsPerPlatform": True
}
```

Comment: Is this possible for language-specific settings as well?

Comment: maybe. try to browse the json file for the global VScode settings. every option that exists is in there.

Comment: The problem is that language specific options have nested syntax in the JSON config, and I don't see how to transfer this nested notation into the `ignoredSettings` array.